# com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, inputstream

I am trying to fetch from S3 bucket but I am getting key as null.

Here is my code :

```
    @Value("${base.location}")
    private String keyname;

    @Value("${os.s3.key}")
    private String fileName;

    @Autowired
    ReadFromS3 readFromS3;

    StringBuilder fileURI = new StringBuilder(keyname);
    fileURI.append(fileName);
  
    InputStream ts = readFromS3.getResourceStream(fileURI.toString()); //null Pointer Exception
```

Here is my application.properties file

```
           base.location=option/output_files
           os.s3.key =${S3_KEYNAME}
           S3_KEYNAME =MY_FILE.txt
```

Here is my getResourceStream method

```
@Override
public InputStream getResourceStream(String keyName) {

    S3ObjectInputStream s3objectStream = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName))
            .getObjectContent();
    return s3objectStream; // The specified key does not exist.
}

I added Loggers and the keyname is option/output_files/MY_FILE.txt
```

I don't understand what it means with the "specified key".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon S3 exception: "The specified key does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653249/amazon-s3-exception-the-specified-key-does-not-exist)

Comment: What is the value of `keyName`? It should _not_ start with a slash.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein value of key name is MY_FILE.txt , I have corrected the keyname in the question

Comment: I suggest you **add some debug statements** to see the true value of `bucketName` and `keyName` that are passed to `getObject()` since it is saying that the object doesn't exist. They might not be what you expect!